# Is $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ be distinct real numbers. For $i = 1, 2, 3$, let $f_i \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ be the function 
      $f_i(t)=e^{a_it}$
. 
Which  of the following statement(s) is/are true?

(A) $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly independent

(B) $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly dependent.

(C) $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ form a basis of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: my answer is option A and C, because  if we  check the linearly independent that is,,,,,  $c_1f_1 + c_2f_2 + c_3f_3 =0$ , $f_i(t)=e^{a_it} \neq 0$ where $c_1= c_2 = c_3= 0$,,,so  $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ will form a basis of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ that mean $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are linearly independent..so correct option is opton A and option C,,,

Is my answer is correct or incorrect. pliz verified my answer and tell me the solution,

Comment: Consult this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the correct answer is A. They don't for a basis of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$. For instance, you cannot express the identity as a linear combination of your functions.

Comment: @ josecarlos santos,,,,,im not getting...as i have expressed c1f2 +c2f2+c3f3 = 0 where C1=c2=c3= 0,,,,,here it is clearly see that f1 ,f2 and f3 are linearly independent,,,,so they will forms  basis,,

Comment: @lomberlego How do you define basis?

Comment: @ jose Carlos santos,,here i m getting three function,,,f1(t)=e^a1t , and f2(t) =e^a2t and f3(t) = e^a3(t)....these three are function are linearly independent,,,so they will form basis

Comment: @lomberlego Please answer my question: how do you define basis?

Comment: @ jose carlos santos,,,, collection B = { v 1, v 2, …, v r } of vectors from V is said to be a basis for V if B is linearly independent and spans V. ......

Comment: @ jose carlos santos,,that mean it will not span,,,so it will not form basis,,,Am  i right ?

Comment: @lomberlego Correct. Your vectors are indeed linearly independent, but they do *not* span $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @lomberlego You are right.

Comment: thanks  a lots @ jose carlos santos,,,,marked ..+1 and accepted

Comment: @lomberlego Thank you.